# Cocos2d: thread error when trying to add background music

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, simpleaudioengine, side-scroller

Hello I am making a cocos2d side scroller. I am trying to add a background audio file. I am using SimpleAudioEngine. This is the code:

```
[[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine]playBackgroundMusic:@"Soundtrack.mp3" loop:YES];
```

But when I run it it gives me a error. The line that it says is giving me the error is:

```
[audioSourcePlayer prepareToPlay];
```

Is there a different way to add a sound file that won't give me this error?

Comment: aaand what would that error be? What's in the debug console?

Comment: never mind i took out the exception breakpoints I had and it began to work again!

Answer (score 3):

The AVAudio and OpenAL will throw some exceptions, it's normal that the Xcode exception breakpoint triggers and nothing to worry about.

Instead of removing the exception breakpoint I highly recommend to "edit" the breakpoint and from the tiny edit dialog make sure you select that only Objective-C exceptions are caught. That way all the audio exceptions won't bother you (they're C++ exceptions) but you can still see where things crash should an assertion trigger.